# Django app with three tables that need many-to-many fields

Tags: python, mysql, django, many-to-many, mariadb

I have a Django app that I am working on that has three separate tables. The three tables would be a list of servers, a list of databases, and a list of applications. Each of these tables can reference one or more object from both of the other tables (eg. a database can be used by multiple applications and reference multiple servers if it has been transferred between them for historical purposes). How would something like this be setup with many to many fields in Django (I assume something like two m2m for serverlist and than a single m2m for the databaselist to the application list but I have been unable to find any examples of something like this).

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you looking for.

```
class Server(models.Model):

    """
    model class for server
    """

    databases = models.ManyToManyField('Database',
                                     related_name='server_databases')

    applicaitons = models.ManyToManyField('Applications',
                                         related_name='server_applications')

class Database(models.Model):

    """
    model class for Database
    """

    applications = models.ManyToManyField('Database',
                                     related_name='databases')

class Applicaiton(models.Model):
    """
    model class for application
    """

   #add fields of application model
```

Comment: Looks like that may work for what I need. I will give it a try and let you know, thank you.